# Shining object in the sky resembling a star

Tags: astronomy

From last 2 days I am observing a shiny star like shining object in the sky in almost same place at same time. Is there any possibility that it could be a satellite? Will satellite shine like a star in the sky due to any kind of reflection from the sun. I see it in the evening and in white light. I don't know how to verify but I am very curious to know what it is.

Comment: I not 100% sure, but I think that satellites move very fast compared to a star. So you could know if it's a satellite using a camera.

Comment: It would have to be a geo-synchronous satellite to stay in the same place. Those are quite far out, and I don't think you can see the sunlight reflecting off of one with your naked eye. You can definitely see satellites in low earth orbit at night with the right sun angle, but those will be obviously moving, even if just watching it for a second or two. These take something like 15 minutes to go horizon to horizon.  What makes you think it isn't a star?

Comment: Do you have an iPad? There are a couple of great free apps for identifying both celestial objects and satellites.

Comment: Its very bright unlike any star.and it is moving.i was riding and found it in a different location after some time.

Comment: Could it be a high flying airplane? If the Sun reflects off the bottom of an airplace it can make the plane appear as an incandescant spot.

Comment: Would http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/ be a better home for this question?

Comment: There is not nearly enough information here to be answered on any site. **When exactly** was this seen? **Where** on Earth did you observe this? **Where** was the object? **How** did it move? A lot? A little? **With respect to background stars?** (After all, the stars move just as much as the Sun or Moon.) Was it in the **East or West** or some other direction? Did it flicker? How dark is your sky (how many stars can you see)?

Comment: i saw it at 7pm when it is dark sky where i couldnt see much stars,the stars(almost 3or 4) with normal size and this one was approximately 3 to 4 times bigger insize.i saw it at same time for 2 days.yesterday and day before.it is not twinkling.i use to watch moon while riding and notices that when i move in a straight line,it always be in my same side.But this one move a lot with respect to me, made me feel that that distance is much lesser between me and the thing or that object itself should be moving little faster.please help me identify whether its a satellite or venus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bright "star" in the evening = Venus

http://www.universetoday.com/106160/bright-venus-takes-center-stage-in-november/

Comment: That was my first thought, but then nemu says in a comment: *Its very bright unlike any star.and it is moving*

Comment: Well it is brighter than any star and it "moves" as the Earth rotates :-)

Answer (score 2):

This great software can help you identify most celestial objects visible in the night sky.

http://www.stellarium.org/